# Docker networking: containers not communicating

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, networking

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    api:
        image: my-api
        ports: 
            - "8090:8090"
    webapp:
        build: ./
        ports:
            - "8082:8082"
```

In my webapp, I have a properties file with the URL of the api service

```
api.url=http://api:8090/platform
```

The webapp code then calls the web service using that api, but it's not working.  I'll get an error like this

```
Fail, Return Code: 404
```

I've tried using 'host.docker.internal' or 'docker' as well, but those don't work either.  What am I doing wrong?  The webapp is running in tomcat 8.5, jdk 8.

Answer (score 0):

The `404` status code is an http error code that requires the connection to have succeeded. That status code came from the `api` container, and so you have connectivity between the containers. You should be looking at why the `/platform` path is not returning content in your `api` service.

Comment: Maybe that 404 is coming downstream from another call then. I'm monitoring the logs on the api service and it never fires when I run the action from my webapp that should be calling it.

I know that the api service is running fine as well because I can connect to it from Postman and get valid responses, and I see the api service logs firing off when I call it.  When I set the url to another instance of the api service that is not running in a container, it works fine, so I know that the webapp code is ok.

Comment: @wlaem I'm afraid there's not enough in this question for me to attempt to reproduce your issue. However, from what you provided, `api:8090` is correct.

Comment: Turns out I just had the url path incorrect.  Thanks for your help